# Minimum cost closed walk in a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-hard, graph-traversal, traveling-salesman

Is there an efficient algorithm which gives the minimum cost closed walk in an undirected graph, which visits all vertices?

Does this problem have a name? I tried to reduce this to similar problems (in particular the traveling salesman problem) to see if it was NP-hard, but was unsuccessful.

Here's an example:

[image]

Then a possible closed walk is: A,B,C,D,C,B,A, with a cost of 6.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like this problem is similar to the [route inspection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem) with the modification that you are interested in exploring all the vertices instead of all the edges. However there does not seem to be a way to reduce this problem to it.

Comment: What is a minimum distance closed walk?

Comment: I meant minimum cost, updated the question.

Comment: [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7606/need-an-efficient-algorithm-to-visit-all-nodes-of-a-graph-revisiting-edges-and) "Take a graph with $n$ vertices, put $1$'s on all edges, compute optimum walk. If its weight is $n−1$ then you managed to visit every vertex exactly once, so the graph is Hamiltonian"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7606/need-an-efficient-algorithm-to-visit-all-nodes-of-a-graph-revisiting-edges-and), by finding the minimum cost closed walk (or just it's cost) of an arbitrary 4-regular planar graph, with weights 1, we can decide whether it has a Hamiltonian Path, but this problem is NP-complete. So the original problem is NP-hard.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is equivalent to TSP. Compute all pairwise shortest distances between the vertices in the given graph $G$. Then take the complete graph $K_n$ that is weighted with the shortest-distances of the original graph $G$. The TSP tour of the complete graph corresponds to the shortest min-cost closed walk.

More precisely, a shortest tour $\pi$ in $K_n$ decodes a closed walk in $G$: just replace every edge $(u,v)$ in $\pi$ by the shortest path from $u$ to $v$. Clearly, the costs are preserved. Assume that there would be a shorter closed walk in $G$. Select select the vertices in order they appear first. This permutation implies a tour in $K_n$ (maybe even shorter than the closed walk in $G$), hence we have a contradiction.

See the figure for your example.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the converse, i.e. how does this reduce from TSP?

Comment: I don't see the logic, since $K_n$ is arbitrary, why does replacing edge costs with shortest path costs not change the tour?